# error in vagrant up Virtualmachin in Homestead - Laravel

Tags: git, laravel, laravel-5, virtualbox, homestead

I have a problem with command 'vagrant up' in larval Homestead installation and need help for this problem, thanks

[Img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNCMt.png)
[Img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eIfK.png)

Comment: Did u try reset it in VirtualBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something went wrong with configuring the box. Try `vagrant destroy` and then `vagrant up` again.

Comment: Yes, I try `vagrant destroyed and the same problem I think I have a problem with the second network card when I disable the card I can launch the VM manually.